# sharepoint jquery for sum of two column

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

i need jquery that fill column in a sharepoint list based on the sum of two columns that are the type text. the format in text column is Г:2 М:05 Д: 10. the formula would works next: Г:2 М:05 Д: 10 + Г:5 М:03 Д: 1 = Г:7 М:08 Д: 11

Г is year

M is month

D is day

there is a problem here for the Д and M. the M are months, if we add for example 10+15=25 months, that is 2 years and 1 month, those two years should be transferred to Г:, and this 1 should be written in М:. The same applies to days
can you help me?
[image]